# Froala editor Change placeholder

Tags: froala

After clicking the video icon in the toolbar,  a popup appears which says "Paste in a video url" as a placeholder inside a field to paste a video URL.

Is there any way to change this placeholder?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the text in the language files (js/languages/*.js).

Search for `Paste in a video URL` and change the text.